# .htaccess rewrite rule doesn't append path to query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, query-string

I'm trying to write an htaccess file and I'm having trouble getting it to work properly.  There's a directory on my site called 'gpio'.  The htaccess file that I'm writing is in /var/www/gpio.

When someone requests the URL http://domain.com/gpio, I want the request to be redirected to a script, with 'gpio' appended to the query string.  This is what I've got in my htaccess file:

```
# .htaccess
#DirectoryIndex index.html
RewriteEngine on

# I changed domain name a few months ago...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com/*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# handle the case where the directory exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
# this is the part that doesn't work
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cgi-bin/pyindex.cgi?q=$1 [L,QSA]

# handle the case where a file is requested
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cgi-bin/pyindex.cgi?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The problem is that when I visit this URL, I get redirected to the script, but the requested path doesn't get appended to the query string. In pyindex.cgi, when the query string is printed, it just contains 'q='.  The end result is that I'm seeing my home page when I should be seeing a page representing a category of posts.

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either have that rule inside `/var/www/.htaccess` or modify it as

```
RewriteRule ^$ /cgi-bin/pyindex.cgi?q=gpio [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ /cgi-bin/pyindex.cgi?q=gpio/$1 [L,QSA]
```

And, the following rule tests if the request is **not** a file (and hence would match directories as well)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  # remove ! to match files
```

Comment: Thanks Ravi. I put the code in /var/www/.htaccess and that solved the problem.